# Javascript Creating, Calling and Triggering Custom Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am creating my own class/library/sdk using webpack and node.

It basically takes an image and submits it to an api and then does some other time consuming functionality which is irrelevant.

But because this `submit()` function is asynchronous, i want to add callback functionality so a user knows if and when it has completed or errored.

Below is sort of how i see a user initialising it and also listening to an `onSuccess` or `onError` callback.

**Client Javascript**

```
<button onclick="hsp.submit()" type="button">Submit</button>
```

-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const hsp = new HSP("123");

    hsp.onSuccess(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    hsp.onError(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

</script>
```

**Library**

```
var HSFileReader = require('./helper/filereader');
var api = require('./api');

    class HSP {

        constructor(product) {

    }
        async submit() {

            try {

           //action 1 
           //action 2
           //action 3
           // if it reaches the end it has completed call success


            } catch (e) {
                throw "Error(submit): Failed to submit" + e;
            }
        }

        onSuccess(response) {

        }

        onError(errors) {

        }

    }

    module.exports = HSP;
```

So in that **async submit()** function i do 3 actions (e.g calling an external api). If all actions are complete i want to trigger this onSuccess callback so the client knows it completed and get the response. If any errors occur similarly i want to trigger the onError callback?

So my question is assuming the above is the appropriate way of handling this, how do i trigger these callbacks in my submit function?

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

try this

```
var api = require('./api');

class HSP {

    constructor(product) { }

    async submit() {
        try {
       //action 1 
       //action 2
       //action 3
       // if it reaches the end it has completed call success
       return someValue;

        } catch (e) {
            throw "Error(submit): Failed to submit" + e;
        }
    }

}

module.exports = HSP;
```

on the init do

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const hsp = new HSP("123");

    const submitOnClick = async () => {
         try {
             const response = await hsp.submit();
             // handle the response
         } catch(e) {
            // handle the errors
         }

    }

</script>
```

and

```
<button onclick="submitOnClick()" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my requirements. The submit function is very long. At the end of it i want to let my client know it was a success or if there was an error. Seems like you are setting it the wrong way.

Comment: in shortened can you explain what wrong with the setting here. as i see it the user create the object, set the callbacks he needed to be execute, and on the submit method implementation you execute those methods . the execution of the callback is his way of listening to the status of the submit method